# How do I understand these multiple complements?

Tags: complements

> “And we believe that the best situation for all parties involved would be for us to have custody of Zoe, to raise her in a warm and stable family situation, to provide her with the kind of upbringing and, well, not to be gauche, but privileges we can provide for her.”
>
> (Garth Stein, The Art of Racing in the Rain)

I guess the subject, *the best situation*, is followed by three complements: (1) to have custody of Zoe, (2) to raise her in a warm and stable family situation, (3) to provide her with the kind of upbringing – *for us* is common agent for to-clauses. And after *and* is the second complement for believe. But there are two strangeness for me: (1) what *not to be gauche* mean? Is it modest expression for the speaker?, (2) If *but*-clause is really the complement, why does the book adopt *but*? Is it mean *only* privileges (they can provide her *only* with privileges)? Or is *but* related with the previous phrase, *not to be gauche*?

Comment: Yes, to be gauche is an expression of modesty or humility. It's like saying, *well not to be **crude**, but* ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject of the sentence is ***we***. It's the subject of the verb ***believe***. The relative pronoun *that* is functioning as a conjunction that's joining another relative clause.

The subject of that relative clause is this noun clause: *best situation for all parties involved*, which is the subject of *would be*.

The clauses are elliptical. They're all using the subject and verbs *we believe* and the entire relative clause that follows them. I'm not sure that I'd call them complements *per se*. I suppose they could be considered subject complements though.

There are a couple of ways that this could be written to make this more clear:

> **We believe that the best situation for all parties involved would be for us** to have custody of Zoe. **We believe that the best situation
>   for all parties involved would be [*for us*]** to raise her in a warm
>   and stable family situation. **We believe that the best situation for
>   all parties involved would be [*for us*]** to provide her with the
>   kind of upbringing and, well, not to be gauche, but privileges we can
>   provide for her.

*For us* is extraneous because it is implied by the subject/verb *we believe*, so I've removed it from all but the first clause.

Semi-colons could perhaps make this more clear:

> And we believe that the best situation for all parties involved would
>   be for us to have custody of Zoe; to raise her in a warm and stable
>   family situation; [***and***] to provide her with the kind of
>   upbringing and, well, not to be gauche, but privileges we can provide
>   for her

It could also be read as a bullet point list:

> **And we believe that the best situation for all parties involved would be for us:**
>
> 1. To have custody of Zoe;
> 2. To raise her in a warm and stable family situation;
> 3. To provide her with the kind of upbringing and, well, not to be
>      gauche, but privileges we can provide for her.

They're not *technically* independent clauses because they can't stand on their as written, but they are complete thoughts.

> (1) what not to be gauche mean? Is it modest expression for the
>   speaker?

*Gauche* means *crude, crass, coarse*, etc.

> (2) If but-clause is really the complement, why does the book adopt
>   but?

The tricky part of this is that *but* is actually the **end** of the clause. That clause is: ***well, not to be gauche, but [anyway, as I was saying,]***. The text in the brackets is what's being implied.

What's happening is that there is a break in speech between the coordinating conjunction *and* and the word it's joining with *upbringing*, which is *privileges*. the complete thought is:

We believe that the best situation for all parties involved would be for us to provide her with the kind of upbringing and privileges [***that only***] we
can provide for her.

The speaker has stopped because they know that what they're about to say may portray them in an unflattering light, but they're determined to say it anyway. It at least makes it seem that they don't mean it that way. What they're actually saying is this:

> We believe that the best situation for all parties involved would be
>   for us to provide her with the kind of upbringing and, ***not to be
>   immodest, but,*** privileges we can provide for her.

Alternatively, you could think of it this way:

> We believe that the best situation for all parties involved would be
>   for us to provide her with, ***well, not to be gauche but, the kind of
>   upbringing and privileges we can provide for her.***

Think of the *well, not to be gauche, but* clause as an appositive.

Comment: I love the way you "bullet point" it. But I think that you meant to have three bullet points, perhaps?

Comment: I didn't mean that one, I think you would agree to split "to have custody ..., to raise ..." into two items.

Comment: Yes, sorry, indeed I did mean to have three. That goes to show the value of an independent set of eyes. Strangely, I thought there were supposed to be three when I posted this, and I caught all three in all the other examples, but I glossed over it there. I'll fix it. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.